# Add elements to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm adding values into a object but I want that the object has a particular format like this:

Result: `Object {ES: 16.63, DE: 11.58, US: 158.97, CA: 85.81, IN: 1.1}`

Declaration:

```
var mydata2 = {
              "ES": 16.63,
              "DE": 11.58,
              "US": 158.97,
              "CA": 85.81,
              "IN": 1.1
            };
```

But when I add the object dynamically, I can't do the same and the result is not that I want. For exemple I tried to do this:

```
$.getJSON('countries.json', function(json){
        $.each(json.value.Map, function(index,value){

              cvalue[index]=this.count;

              i++;
        });
        console.log(cvalue);
```

And the result is this one: `[uk: 21, it: 35, jp: 22, ar: 13, us: 123…]`
And expanded:

```
ar: 13
au: 33
be: 160
br: 30
cl: 26
co: 16
...
```

I'm sure that there is a method for do that but I didn't found it.

**EDIT**

The purpose of this question is parse the data to this format: `Object {ES: 16.63, DE: 11.58, US: 158.97, CA: 85.81, IN: 1.1}` because after that I need to get data with this format.

Comment: You want the keys to be uppercase? Is that the question?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What is wrong with your result? What is `cvalue`? Where is that defined?

Comment: @Mathletics Is not that problem. Only I want include the json data with this format `Object {ES: 16.63, DE: 11.58, US: 158.97, CA: 85.81, IN: 1.1}` instead the current format: `[uk: 21, it: 35, jp: 22, ar: 13, us: 123…]`

Comment: @MattBurland The result format is so important because after I need to get the data in this format. `cvalue` is a normal `var` used for save data from json.

Comment: @Lins: That doesn't make sense. What you have (in your comment to Mathletics) isn't valid javascript in the first place. What does your input *actually* look like. Because that definitely isn't it.

Comment: Those two data sets don't seem to be related. I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to use a `MAP`. Possibly `cvalue` is a simple array.

Example of map declaration:

```
var map = new Object();

map[index]=this.count;
```